# Working way to transfer SQLite database to another device without external storage permissions (updates Android 11)

Tags: sqlite, storage, shared, mediastore

With new Shared Storage and new Android API 30 requirements I can't find a way to recover a database on new or another device.
Until this time, I used File API to create a copy of the database. Any time user could put this file to any cloud, download from cloud on another device and restore the database on it. Of course, I used `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Now, Google rejects the app and says that we should use MediaStore API which can solve that issues without any permissions. I tried it and it works only on same device. And until if created the database file not copied to/from cloud or moved to/from another folder. In that case `cursor.getCount == 0`:

```
String[] projections = new String[]{MediaStore.Downloads._ID};
String selection = MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"database.db"};
String sortOrder = MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";
Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL), projections, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
Uri uri = null;
if (cursor != null) {
    int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Downloads._ID);
    cursor.moveToNext();
    long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
    uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
    try {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "rw");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        File dbFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), "/data/com.example.app/databases/database.db");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = fileInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        fileOutputStream.close();
        fileInputStream.close();
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        restartApp();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Something wrong with code or MediaStore API does not provide any actions with created files?

```
E/DBError: exception
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Also I tried Google Drive API to copy the database file on cloud directly from app and download it. But it's not working way too, because new device don't know about file ID which used to download files.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out.
Without any storage permissions your app have access to onw created files with MediaStore API.
But haven't if:

- file was moved/copied inside device storage
- file was uploaded to cloud and then downloaded from it
- app was reinstalled

I tested it on versions 28 (emulation), 29 (device), 30 (emulation).

So in my case anyway I need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="29"/>
```

Don't know why but for read own file on Android Q not enough only `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

I was lucky and Google approved app. Hope you too.